# How to resolve the Entity declarations and get the file path in an XML?

Tags: java, xml, jaxp, entityresolver

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <!DOCTYPE dmodule 
 [<!NOTATION JPEG SYSTEM 'Joint Photographic Experts Group'>
  <!ENTITY abcd SYSTEM  'sunset.jpg' NDATA JPEG>
 ]>

  ....
  <graphic id = "abcd"/>
```

With reference to the above sample code, i need to get the sunset image  on my html for which i need to get the filepath sunset.jpg which is defined in the entity declaration .

How would i do it in Java? 
I tried

```
 document.getDoctype().getEntities().item(i).getNodeName(),
```

but it gives me abcd, but i need the filepath 'sunset.jpg'.

And i also tried,

```
builder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {

            @Override
            public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
                    throws SAXException, IOException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("Public and System IDs"+publicId+"  "+systemId);
                return new InputSource(new StringReader(referDM));
            }
        });
```

but i think i have some problem with the return type as i am expecting an image file to be read as a byte array,? What should be the return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Entity entity = (Entity) document.getDoctype().getEntities().item(i);
String path = entity.getSystemId();
```

Comment: Ah! Works like a charm :) 

I tried doing this earlier but completely forgot to typecast it !
Thanks for the quick solution.